# DataGridView allow paging , why it get all data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

hi i have simple gridView with AllowPaging set to true, i bind data to it as follow:

```
            RulesGridView.DataSource = GetData();
            RulesGridView.DataBind();
```

where

```
 public static IEnumerable GetData()
    {
        return from gc in context.Current.SampleTable
               where gc.SameField == sameValue
               select new
                          {
                              example = SampleData
                          };
    }
```

In sql SampleTable i have 4000 rows, my question is , why gridView is taking all data from this table, instead of only first page of gridview? i checked with sql profiler , and that is really true, displaying just first page on gridview couse downloading all gridview pages. Can i change it to take from sql only so many what is enough to display data on first page of DataGrid, and then if user click second page , gridview will ask for another data?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are binding method which simple returns all records.

Possible solution: You have to modify your GetData method to accept parameter which will mark pagination and apply it in inner query. Then at each "pageNext/Prev" event, you just modify that parameter to new value.

Edit:

[Codeproject custom paging for gridView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/GridViewNeatPaging.aspx)
[Aspsnippets about pagination](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Pagination-in-ASP.Net-Gridview-Control.aspx)

Comment: i thought that it returns some kind of enumerator, which only tells what data need to be retriven,some kind of expresion, and gridView is taking those which need, Dynamic Data works probably like that.

Comment: Yea, sorry. I missed that IEnumerable return type. My bad. Have you set PageIndex and associated properties at your gridview? Btw: I am going add some links for you to my answer.

Comment: well, ok pageIndex is just for displaying another part of data. My question is why if i bind Ienumerable function to GridView, just first page is getting all of data, i don't get it.

Comment: Right.. well I don't know why it takes all, but I guess you could solve it (even when it probably isn't the best solution) with that modification I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I like this discussion http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/211.aspx; it may give you additional insight or decide that it is time to pull every hair from Gates.